# Does PhoneGap / Apache Cordova propose an API for encrypted SQLite database

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I would like to know if it's possible when using PhoneGap/ Apache Cordova to create/access and encrypted SQLite database.

I read I can encrypt before storing/ decrypt after but that's not what I am looking for.

I am rather looking for a PhoneGap plugin or API using something like:

- http://sqlite-crypt.com/

Looking for something like this but encrypted:

- https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Find somebody to port that plugin to use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). It may only work on Android and iOS, but those are the only ones you tagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clear it out: You're always been doing encryption before and decryption after, no matter which method you choose.

If you're tageting Android with Apache Cordova the better option is to develop a plugin in Javascript/Java using the javax.crypto,* API.

An example of encryption and decryption native algorithms in Java:

- http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS4B/Crypto/FileEncryptor.html

And a tutorial to make plugins for Apache Cordova targeting Android:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html

The encryption native lib suitable for iOS:

- https://chiselapp.com/user/thebeing/repository/GS-CommonCrypto/home

The Apache Cordova Plugin approach targeting iOS:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html

Hope it helps